# What is the preferred way to typeset 'et al.'?

Tags: spacing

How should I be entering the abbreviation 'et al.' in my thesis? What is the preferred spacing after the period in 'al.'? Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[oneside,11pt]{book}

\usepackage[semibold,tt=false]{libertine}
\usepackage{libertinust1math}
\usepackage[
  expansion = false ,
  tracking = smallcaps ,
  letterspace = 40 ,
  final
]{microtype}
\begin{document}

\noindent
Bob et al. suggest A.\\
Bob et al.\ suggest A.

\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be the latter version, `et al.\`  In the first instance, TeX is assuming that the period after a lower-case letter indicates a sentence-ending punctuation so adds extra space there. Most cases where this comes up, e.g., Mr. Jones, one naturally uses a non-breaking space after the period. Most, but not all cases of “et al.” have a comma immediately following it (Blank, et al., 1977) but I found sufficient instances of et al. without a comma in a quick Google books search to indicate that this is not an unlikely usage.

(Whether TeX's choice to add extra space after sentence-ending punctuation is a good idea to begin with is a whole separate question.)

Comment: +1. On a separate issue, I would also make the space between "et" and "al." unbreakable.

Comment: @mico I would argue against `et~al.` and for `et al.` Much like one could allow a line break after an ampersand (which is a stylized “et”), there isn't any compelling reason to keep “et” with “al.”

Comment: Many BibTeX styles which provide authoryear-style citation call-outs and I'm familiar with -- including the bib styles provided by the `natbib` and `harvard` citation management packages -- use an unbreakable space between "et" and "al". That said, it's true that the very old `apalike` bib style does *not* employ an unbreakable space.